# kworker causes high CPU and RAM consumption

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kvm, vps

[image: linux-server]

The kworker performs operations that take the Memory, I/O, and CPU highly on my VPS every hour.

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess. You have 97% of your memory used.
`kswapd0` is using 108% of your CPU.

And from the docs

> The `kswapd` process is responsible for managing virtual memory,
> specifically swapping memory pages in and out of physical RAM. If
> `kswapd` is using a high percentage of CPU, it suggests that your system
> is under memory pressure and is constantly trying to free up RAM by
> moving data to swap space.

and the `kworker` proces ist part of the Linux kernel's way of managing various types of background work, like swapping RAM! Usually the kworker proces indicates that there is a lot of such background work at that time. Which is the case, as you see with `kswapd`.

In the picture I only see mostly programs, that are using CPU, And I cannot see much RAM usage, maybe you might try tools like `free -h` or `htop` or `meminfo` to identify processes that are consuming a lot of memory and investigate whether they are behaving as expected and that `ksworker` doesn't need to trigger `kswapd` to swap you RAM.

Good Luck.

Comment: Yes, the RAM usage is not shown when the Kworker is executing also `htop` and `meminfo` cannot capture the RAM usage, but I recorded the video to see the behavior of the server before its peak. (I already disabled the swap)

the link: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsNSud0xLFk